# I want to give force update feature in my app for android users

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 for these and i need to give a force update feature for android users.

can i able to do it with-->
 like first compare current play store version and user version and then set 
 a page for those users who don't have the updated version and force user's 
 for update the app, can i use file transfer plugin for update the app.

what approch is right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use following plugins to verify that updates is available in playstore.

```
cordova-plugin-app-update
```

You should first host an XML file on your server with the following data in it:

```
<update>
   <version>302048</version>
   <name>APK Name</name>
   <url>https://your-remote-api.com/YourApp.apk</url>
</update>
```

And then check with

```
constructor(private appUpdate: AppUpdate) {

 const updateUrl = 'https://your-remote-api.com/update.xml';
 this.appUpdate.checkAppUpdate(updateUrl).then(() => { console.log('Update 
 available') });

}
```

More details available [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-update/)

Comment: this gives me alert 
 Unfortunately , app_name has stopped.
and after that app will crash.
this happenes when encounter 
this.appUpdate.checkAppUpdate(updateUrl).then(result => { debugger; console.log('Update available') });
      }
this code

Comment: @mehul, I did with puts a version information file in my php server and in ionic app i did some code which is available here (https://gist.github.com/chintansoni54/943d90d00415b89aacf59ac365d26df8)
to get current app version you have to use this plugins (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version/)

Comment: app update asking for installation of app after successfully download of new version

Comment: Then might possible that you have different package name. It's not related to forcefully update.

Comment: both apps are exact same , after installation second app replaces first app

Comment: Did you try this with release build package

Comment: @mehul, Then you have to try this on release apk because debug apk and resale apk both are different so it was ask for installation

Comment: Try on other devices which doesn't have your debug apk

Comment: "You should first host an XML file on your server with the following data in it:"

Where i set this file??  in Ionic app or else?

Comment: I'm having success using [capacitor-app-update](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-app-update). Using this, you manually check for version difference wherever you deem appropriate in your app e.g. early, during app mount, before showing any content. You then decide different actions, like forcing the user into a fullscreen Android update experience or give them the option to do a background update. Overall I prefer this explicit method, under my control, rather than relying on Google Play (which will still inform the user of an app update within Google Play's app itself).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this with release build package  ?

Comment: i have tried with release apk as well but it gives me installation

Comment: it's still asking manually installation of download updated apk